# Format PromQL values

Tags: prometheus, slack, promql

i use this query rule for alert:

```
- alert: HostOutOfMemory

    expr: (1 - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes) * 100 > 90

    for: 5m

    labels:

      severity: warning

    annotations:

      summary: "{{ $labels.name }} out of memory "

      description: "Host memory is {{ $value }}%"
```

But the value is float (default of PromQL), i want to format it (the picture below, can i change it to show only 90%), how can i do it ?

[image]

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prometheus templating language is based on the [Go templating system](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/). There are many [examples in the documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_examples/).

In your specific case you would use:

```
 description: Host memory is {{ $value | printf "%.2f%" }}.
```

There are also some builtin functions in Prometheus that can be of interest like `humanizePercentage`:

```
- alert: HostOutOfMemory
  expr: (1 - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes) > 0.9
  ...
  annotations:
    description: Host memory is {{ $value | humanizePercentage }}
```

Comment: I do not know why, but when I use `{{ $value | humanizePercentage }}` and my value is like `11.76470588235294`, then the output is `1176%`.

Comment: humanizePercentage expects a fraction ration (between 0 and 1). See https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_reference/#numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can also use round() function, write all of your expr into the round and it will show the value correctly